# Android OutOfMemory Problem

Tags: android, sql, memory, out-of-memory

I am parsing a binary file on the device and storing fields I care about in arrays. These files can lead to arrays that are 100,000's in size. Naturally, java tells me I run out of memory (I think android only allows 16MB per application).

Is there another way to grab this data?

Basically, I parse for points and color information, store it in arrays, then use vertexBuffers to draw these in OpenGL. Storing them in a database wouldn't help me, would it?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I run a parse on a file with 482,000 points. It stores position and color without crashing. I see this in debugger:

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 43.164MB for 23156032-byte allocation
Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 30874704-byte allocation
Out of memory on a 30874704-byte allocation
```

The error populates on `java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` 
I've included that code area below:

```
//Parse file and populate arrays
PointParser(fileName, header);

// a float is 4 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if 
// vertices with 4.
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasVertices.length * 4);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(lasVertices);
vertexBuffer.position(0);   

ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasColors.length * 4);
cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
colorBuffer.put(lasColors);
colorBuffer.position(0);
```

...

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glPointSize(0.6f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, numVertices);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
```

Comment: @Francesco I have a couple of arrays of floats. I was hoping to somehow use a database but I don't know if I can implement that with OpenGL vertex drawing...

Comment: Do you need them all loaded at once? If you're not plotting 100,000+ points in one go then why not break down what you're doing and only create/load/process what you need at that time?

Comment: @Poldie I'm processing a special 3D point cloud. The way I understand the OpenGL-ES on android is that you point an array into a vertex buffer and it draws it from there. I don't know how I could dynamically swap the data so it could all get drawn... does that make sense? - thank you.

Comment: In OpenGL there's no reason why you can't do multiple calls.  Plot 1000 points in each of 100 calls, for example.  But 16MB should be enough for 100,000 points. 100,000 * 3 (x,y) * 4 (bytes per point) is little more than a meg.

Comment: When the out of memory happen? Does it happen during the file reading or during the rendering routine?

Comment: @Poldie - Thanks for helping me with this. First, I parse through my binary file and collect position and color information for anywhere between 60k - 2M points (each requires 3 float values), as well as an equal amount of colors. These each go into their respective array. The parsing is done before any drawing, and I can't parse while I draw. Is the problem in me storing the points, or sending the points into the VBO to be drawn? -thank you!

Comment: @Francesco - I think its during rendering(ish) I included much more info into my original question. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it could help you, but there are lots of interresting advices from google aubout memory management here: http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/